# Django How improve query_params filter

Tags: django, python-3.x

i'm filtering my view queryset base on the request query_params but I don't like how i do it, is there any way to do this most pythonic?

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Publication.objects

    if self.request.query_params.get('user'):
        user = self.request.query_params.get('user')
        if user.isdigit():
            qs = qs.filter(owner__pk=user)

    limit = self.request.query_params.get('limit')
    if limit and limit.isdigit():
        return qs.all()[:int(limit)]
    return qs.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

`.get` takes a second `default` argument so you don't have to check if parameter exists or not. If request data does not contain `user`, it will be `''`. So, this might be better:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Publication.objects

    user = self.request.query_params.get('user', '')
    limit = self.request.query_params.get('limit', '')

    if user.isdigit():
        qs = qs.filter(owner__pk=user)

    if limit.isdigit():
        return qs.all()[:int(limit)]

    return qs.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = Publication.objects.all()

    user = self.request.query_params.get('user', None)
    limit = self.request.query_params.get('limit', None)

    if user:
       qs = qs.filter(owner__pk=user)

    if limit:
       return qs[:int(limit)]

    return qs
```